# How to display a dictionary or array variable in odoo widget?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

While displaying a variable its working but not an array

widget.js

```js
init: function() {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.num_field=123;
    this.arr_field=["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]
},
```

widget.xml

```xml
<t t-raw="num_field" ></t>
<t t-foreach="arr_field" t-as="arr">
    <t t-raw="arr" ></t>
</t>
```

In above `num_field` is working but `arr_field` is not working.
How to display that?

Answer (score 2):

you can try **t-esc** :

```
<t t-foreach="arr_field" t-as="arr">
    <t t-esc="arr" />
</t>
```